# Mobius transformation that maps $|z+i|=1$ to $|w|=4$

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification, mobius-transformation

In Silverman's complex analysis textbook, he described how to find Mobius transformation that maps $|z+i|=1$ to $|w|=4$.

Let $T:\Bbb C_\infty\to\Bbb C_\infty$ be a Mobius transformation that we require. Then $Tz = \frac{az+b}{cz+d}$ for some $a,b,c,d\in\Bbb C$ such that $ad-bc \neq 0$. WLOG, let $T(-i) = \infty$. Then we can reduce the form to $Tz =\frac{az+b}{z+i}$. Since two poins $0,-2i$ in $|z+i| = 1$ should maps to points in $|w|=4$ and $T(0) = -ib$ and $T(-2i) = 2a+ib$, $|b| = 4$ and $\sqrt{4a^2+b^2} = 4$. Hence, we may choose $b = 4$ and $a = 0$. This gives $T(z) = \frac{4}{z+i}$. And then the book conclude that this is the desired map. I understand that $T$ maps circle to circle but circle that passing $4i$ and $-4i$ are infinitely many. How did he ensure this maps $|z+i| = 1$ to $|w| = 4$?

Comment: Personally, I would choose three points on the given circle and map them to three points (in the same order, if I wish inside to map to inside) on the image circle.

Comment: In writing $|T(-2i)|=\sqrt{4a^2+b^2}$, one has implicitly assumed that $a,b$ are real numbers rather than complex. This is a convenient special case but hardly required. In particular this condition forces $T(0)$ to lie on the imaginary axis so one must have $T(0)=\pm 2i$. That reduces from infinitely many circles to just two.

Comment: @TedShifrin That was also my first thought

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that if $|z+i|=1$, then $|T(z)| = \left|\frac 4{z+i}\right| = 4$.